# Struggling with main and master branch in GitHub

Tags: github

I am currently solving Project Euler problems and want to document my progress by uploading my code to GitHub. I can't figure out where to proceed from here, I want all my code to be displayed here in the repository but instead am getting something like this. I want the code to be displayed in the main branch.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxhEE.png)

I want my code files to be displayed in the main branch itself, and I am not sure what "Compare and pull requests" means.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/about-git